# Select next and previous element from ArrayList selected value

Tags: java, android, arraylist

In my android application i want to get all previous and after elements from `ArrayList` selected value. I am using following code for this but its not working.

```
ListIterator<Integer> iterator = photoall_id.listIterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    new  GetImage().execute(url);
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
    System.out.println(iterator.previous());
}
```

this give `random` values repeatedly. I want to get data from selected position of `ArrayList`.

Comment: Why you are not using the indices while accessing the ArrayList?

Comment: I agree with @MustansarSaeed, just use a loop and access the elements with `list.get(i-1)` and `list.get(i+1)`.

Comment: please give me in detailed

Comment: @krishna look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `Iterator.previous()` to print it, you have to call again `Iterator.next()` otherwise you could be stack in an infinite loop.

By the way the simplest solution is using the index:

```
List<Integer> photoall_id= new ArrayList<Integer>();

int mySelectedId= 3;
int indexOfSelectedId = photoall_id.indexOf(mySelectedId);
if(indexOfSelectedId < 0)
    return; //your value is not in the list
//Print previous values
for(int i = 0; i < indexOfSelectedId ; i++)
{
    System.out.println(photoall_id.get(i));
}
//Print next values
for(int i = indexOfSelectedId + 1 ; i < photoall_id.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(photoall_id.get(i));
}
```

Or in only one cicle:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < photoall_id.size(); i++)
{
    if(i != indexOfSelectedId)
       System.out.println(photoall_id.get(i));
}
```

Comment: get elements repeatedly

Comment: what are you mean with repeatedly ? I really don't understand what you want

Answer (score 0):

When you go `next()` followed by `previous()` your `iterator` pointer remains at same position. See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous())

> Note that alternating calls to next and previous will return the same element repeatedly.

My Advice to this is go one step back (`previous()`) and two step forward (`next()`).

```
ListIterator<Integer> iterator = photoall_id.listIterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    new  GetImage().execute(url);
    if(iterator.hasPrevious())
    {
        System.out.println(iterator.previous());
        iterator.next(); //Coming back to current position
        System.out.println(iterator.next()); // to next to current
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
}
```

Hope this help you.